# Resizing bitmaps

Tags: android

I'm writing a Music application and I have already gotten the album arts. However, they came up in various sizes. So, how do I standardized the size of the returned bitmap ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd do something like this:

```
// load the origial BitMap (500 x 500 px)
        Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
               R.drawable.android);

        int width = bitmapOrg.width();
        int height = bitmapOrg.height();
        int newWidth = 200;
        int newHeight = 200;

        // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

        // createa matrix for the manipulation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // resize the bit map
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

        // recreate the new Bitmap
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,
                          width, height, matrix, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could scale the bitmap to the required size when you draw it on the canvas:

From the android documentation:

> drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint) 
>   Draw the specified bitmap, scaling/translating automatically to fill the destination rectangle.

Make src null and dst is a Rect the size/position you want it on the canvas, set up like

```
Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height)
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rect)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the code in the accepted answer does not work, at least on some platforms.

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);
```

will give you a downsampled image at the full size of the original - so just a blurry image.

Interestingly enough, the code

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(square, (int) targetWidth, (int) targetHeight, false);
```

also gives the blurry image.  In my case it was necessary to do this:

```
// RESIZE THE BIT MAP

// According to a variety of resources, this function should give us pixels from the dp of the screen
// From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp-in-android
float targetHeight = DWUtilities.convertDpToPixel(80, getActivity());
float targetWidth = DWUtilities.convertDpToPixel(80, getActivity());

// However, the above pixel dimension are still too small to show in my 80dp image view
// On the Nexus 4, a factor of 4 seems to get us up to the right size
// No idea why.
targetHeight *= 4;
targetWidth *= 4;

matrix.postScale( (float) targetHeight / square.getWidth(), (float) targetWidth / square.getHeight());


Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(square, 0, 0, square.getWidth(), square.getHeight(), matrix, false); 

// By the way, the below code also gives a full size, but blurry image
// Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(square, (int) targetWidth, (int) targetHeight, false
```

I don't have a further solution on this yet, but hopefully this is helpful to someone.