# Expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am developing android application. I am finding following problem which isdisplayed by output image below. Please help me to solve my problem. [Xml file](http://pastebin.com/M6j6sCx1)

Output Screenshot -

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: please show us the xml layout file for the rows

Comment: add xml file for rows, that you use in your adapter, not layout for expandableListView, or add the source of your adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setIndicatorBounds.

Dev link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setIndicatorBounds(int, int)

Example:
http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.com/2011/07/expandable-list-view-move-group-icon.html

Check this stackoverflow link for more info:
[Expandable list view move group icon indicator to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800426/expandable-list-view-move-group-icon-indicator-to-right)

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to your Expandable Listview -

```
android:indicatorRight
```

Once upon a time i've also done by this method only. Hope this helps you.