# Expandable list view move group icon indicator to right in jellyBean 4.3 version?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-4.3-jelly-bean

The below method is not working in android version jellybean 4.3.

```
historyExpaLV.setIndicatorBounds(historyExpaLV.getRight() - 60,
                    historyExpaLV.getWidth() - 8);
```

Does anyone know the solution?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "not working" is not a very useful explanation of your symptoms.

Comment: Does it work in previous versions? Are you calling it before it's measured? More detail, please.

Comment: yes it is working in previous versions Geobits.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How I fixed this:

Update SDK Manager to Android 4.3 and use it as build target. They introduced a new method in the API 18, called **setIndicatorBoundsRelative(int, int)**, which works as the other (but correctly) in android 4.3.

Make a check for Android version and use the old method with older API:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
   mListView.setIndicatorBounds(myLeft, myRight);
} else {
   mListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(myLeft, myRight);
}
```

Comment: but why was this change made ?

Comment: What is myLeft, myRight ? Please elaborate it

Comment: myLeft and myRight are your desired values how you want to pad the indicator. They are called "my" because it's up to you to decide what you want them to be. Check out the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setIndicatorBounds(int, int)

Comment: A cleaner solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706231/put-on-the-right-the-indicator-of-an-expandablelistview-in-android

Answer (score 5):

i think it's bug

```
int right = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels - TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 30, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
    expandableListView.setIndicatorBounds(right - getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.group_indicator_padding).getIntrinsicWidth(), right);
```

this code works fine up to 4.2.2 and do nothing on 4.3

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer...Which is solved my group indicator image size statically...

Comment: Above answer will work for you. As setIndicatorBoundsRelative will work for Android >= 4.3