# Expandable list view move group icon indicator to left in jellyBean 4.3 version?

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Expandable list view moving group icon indicator to left in jellyBean 4.3 version but in all below versions indicator showing at right side. Here is my code,

expList.setIndicatorBounds(expList.getRight()- objBLCommonOperations.getDip(95), expList.getWidth());

Does any one know what is the reason? Thanks in advance.

Comment: setIndicatorBounds method is not working in 4.3 version. Please help me to find out solution.

Comment: I fixed this by doing like this..                    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
   mListView.setIndicatorBounds(left, right);
} else {
   mListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(reft, right);

Comment: Please check similar question with solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995491/expandable-list-view-move-group-icon-indicator-to-right-in-jellybean-4-3-version