# Put on the right the indicator of an ExpandableListView in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview

[image: example]

I have to move the indicator from the left to the right (because of the plane image). I couldn't succeed also because the expandableviewlist is inside a fragment and not inside a whole activity. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: are you talking about arrow image ?

Comment: yes I talk about that one!

Comment: All XML solution based on layout:direction can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38079569/4160084

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expandable list view move group icon indicator to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800426/expandable-list-view-move-group-icon-indicator-to-right)

Answer (score 130, accepted):

I don't know a way to do that from XML but i'll tell you a way to do so dynamically in your adapter.

First you have to remove group indicator from your xml

```
 <ExpandableListView [...] 
    android:groupIndicator="@null" />
```

Then in your layout of the parent add an imageview in the right position of your layout.

Then in your custom adapter do the following

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  ...

    if (isExpanded) {
        groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_down);
    } else {
        groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_up);
    }
  ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks man, Its working like a charm guys, just implement it.

Comment: @Filnik what is a `groupHolder` ?? ViewGroup parent or LayoutInflater or what??

Comment: It's a holder for the group views list.. For example if your group view contains a textview and an imageview. 
Then the group holder class should be like
private static class GroupHolder{
             ImageView img;
             TextView textView;
}

Comment: This is the cleanest solution I have seen so far.

Answer (score 16):

One more solution is:
1) First set groupIndicator in your ExpandableListView to @null:

```
<ExpandableListView [...] 
    android:groupIndicator="@null" />
```

2) Then create group_indicator.xml file with following details:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/down_icon" android:state_selected="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/up_icon" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/down_icon"></item>
</selector>
```

3) Then create group_header.xml layout with following details and inflate this layout in getGroupView() method of ExpandableListAdapter.java:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivGroupIndicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/group_indicator"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

3) In getGroupView() method of your ExpandableListAdapter.java class, just set the following:

```
ivGroupIndicator.setSelected(isExpanded);
```

With this approach, your down_icon and up_icon will work properly.
Hope this helps.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know the android resource file for `down_icon` and `up_icon`, would you?

Answer (score 9):

put this into your xml view:

```
<ExpandableListView
...
android:layoutDirection="rtl" />
```

than you can set the gravity of your text title in your layout item according your preference.

your text view parent list item:

```
<TextView
...
android:gravity="center"/>
```

eg. result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

another solution to put the indicator on the right programmatically:

```
expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        Resources r = getResources();
        int px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                50, r.getDisplayMetrics());
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            expandableListView.setIndicatorBounds(width - px, width);
        } else {
            expandableListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(width - px, width);
        }
```

where `expandableListView` is your `ExpandableListview`

Answer (score -14):

In your groupcustom.xml file you can use Relativelayout and put that image to

```
android:alignParentRight = "true";
```

Comment: I have to put the arrow to the right, not the plane! And the arrow is a custom icon of the expandableListview.. so I cannot change its position :(