# How to set groupindicator in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

Is there a way to set the group indicator image in expandablelistview in android?
I want to set the image of a especific item group. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put your group indicator to the left of the group item you can add the following property to your expandable listview code in xml .. "`android:groupIndicator`"

Otherwise if you want to get this indicator into the right side of your listview you can follow this post [Put on the right the indicator of an ExpandableListView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21706231/put-on-the-right-the-indicator-of-an-expandablelistview-in-android/21707031#21707031)