# Android - Expandable Listview SetIndicatorBounds are not working in Kitkat android-4.4

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, android-4.4-kitkat

Expandable Listview SetIndicatorBounds are not working in my project code.

Here is my Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center|center_vertical"
android:weightSum="1.0"
>               
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/custom_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    />  
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is my code :

```
lv1 = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int width = metrics.widthPixels; 

lv1.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetPixelFromDips(50), width - GetPixelFromDips(10));


public int GetPixelFromDips(float pixels) {

    // Get the screen's density scale 

    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale

    return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);

}
```

My Moto G kitkat device width is 720 . 
But setIndicatorBounds did not seems to be worked out in my Kitkat device .

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
   mListView.setIndicatorBounds(myLeft, myRight);
} else {
   mListView.setIndicatorBoundsRelative(myLeft, myRight);
}
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18013822/2683275)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!! But ,setIndicatorBoundsRelative is undefined for the type ExpandableListView !!!

Comment: you will have to change the targetSdkVersion to the latest one ( or 4.3) version

Comment: this is my manifest file sdk versions:    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

Comment: it should work then, try a clean or restart your ide..since relative bounds was added in api level 18