# How can I put the drawer toggle button on the right of the action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

Is it possible to put the toggle drawer button on the right side of the action bar? The toggle drawer button is the three bar icon on the left side. It turns into an arrow when drawer is opened (hence the arrow icon). I've already set my drawer on the right, but the button is still on the left. Or should I just make a custom one like that? But how can I use the same animation?

[image]

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800426/expandable-list-view-move-group-icon-indicator-to-right

Comment: Sorry, but it's the button that I need to be moved, not the drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Steps that you have to follow :

1. Make a menu.xml in menu folder :
2. Inflate this menu in your activity and implement action over it :

   ```
   @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
           //Inflating menu
           getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
           return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch(item.getItemId()){
           case R.id.drawer : 

              //Open Drawer from right side

                  drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.Right);

                    // or

                  drawerLayout.openDrawer(rightSlider); //right slider is right listview

                   break;
                 }

           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
   ```
3. Finally in your layout xml file and inside drawer layout do like this :

   ```
   <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/frame_container"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" >
   </FrameLayout>

       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/right_slidermenu"
           android:layout_width="260dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="end"
           android:background="@color/white"
           android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
           android:divider="@color/list_divider"
           android:dividerHeight="1dp"
           android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
           android:overScrollMode="never" />
   ```

Try this....it will help you..:)

Comment: Sorry, but I already have the drawer opening from, and closing to, the right. What I need is for the original toggle drawer button, which is the three lines that animates into an arrow when drawer is open, be put on the right side, and pointing to the other side. Thank you tho :)

Comment: You can change the icon of 3 lines icon to back arrow when drawer is open and change it again when drawer is closed.

Comment: but it happens automatically. and is there anyway to put that button on the right side?

Comment: Actually, I didn't try this one, the only solution i know , i told you .

Comment: Well it's right, but I have a little more code. That's why it's not the answer I need. Thanks though.