# Android Convert Px to Dp (Video Aspect Ratio)

Tags: android, screen-resolution, aspect-ratio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [converting pixels to dp in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp-in-android)

I'm trying to convert pixels to dp.  What is the formula?

Lets convert 640 and 480 into dp.  The docs say this

> The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160)

But I don't think that is what I need (and I don't know how to use this).  I guess I just need the forumla.  I have the code ready:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    switch(metrics.densityDpi)
    {
         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
         int sixForty = ?
         int fourEighty = ?
         break;

         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
         int sixForty = ?
         int fourEighty = ?
         break;

         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
         int sixForty = ?
         int fourEighty = ?
         break;
    }
```

Comment: If you're looking to do a one-off conversion (for instance for exporting sprites from Photoshop), [here's a nifty converter](https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/).

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Instead of trying to infer the dp conversion factor from the screen's density classification, you can simply query it directly:

```
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
float logicalDensity = metrics.density;
```

logicalDensity will then contain the factor you need to multiply dp by to get physical pixel dimensions for the device screen.

```
int px = (int) Math.ceil(dp * logicalDensity);
```

Comment: i need the dp value of PIXELS. I have a video that is 640pixels by 480pixels and I need to get their dp equivalents based upon what density the screen is (I know how to get pixels from dp, but not vice versa)

Comment: To get dp from pixels, divide the density into the pixel value rather than multiply.

Comment: public int convertToDp(int input) {
 // Get the screen's density scale
 final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
 // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
 return (int) (input * scale + 0.5f);
}

Comment: Old question, but why + 0.5 ?

Comment: The +0.5 rounds up to the nearest whole number if necessary.  When converted to integer, everything after the decimal is simply cut off.  The +0.5 ensures that the most "correct" integer is returned.

Comment: I would use `int px = (int) Math.ceil(dp * logicalDensity);` then. At least for educational purposes :-)

Comment: Its really odd the ceil function returns a double.

Comment: I finally made the edit to use a proper Math function instead of  `+ 0.5`...

Comment: I have created online calculator( converter ) you can check it out http://servoper.net/android-design-calculator/