# app crashes when opening multiple image

Tags: android

I am making an app for story books, i have my curlview animation for this app.

My problem is that i dont know what size of image and what resolution should i use for 3.5 inches to 5.0 inches screen.

I always reading on supporting multiple screen size but the problem is that i cannot get that.

All i want is the exact image size in pixel and what is the resolution should i use.

i always use 72 as resolution but i dont know what is the dimension should i use for 3.5 to 5.0 inches screen size.

did anyone knows what should i use? i dont want to read supporting multiple screen size because i already read it and i did not get it.

Thank you to someone who can give me the size i should use that will not get crash in my app.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

As it said in [the Android style guide](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) icon size scale for different screens should follow the 2:3:4:6 scaling ratio. Maybe you can use this ratio for other, not only icon, images too.

Answer (score 0):

As you write you read the documentation, I assume you already read [the Android Best Practices Chapter about Density Independence](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence). If I got your question right, you're looking for the following part of it:

> - The system scales dp units as appropriate for the current screen density.
> - The system scales drawable resources to the appropriate size, based on the current screen density, if necessary
>
> [...]
>   By default, Android scales your bitmap drawables (.png, .jpg, and .gif files) [...] so that they render at the appropriate physical size on each device.

So you basically need to provide an screen-size independent layout, and Android takes care of the rest. However it is encouraged to deliver multiple images for a better scaling quality.

If you can only afford a single size for the images, I'd decide on a target audience (e.g. how likely are Tablet users, what is the average device's screen size in my audience -> how many pixels will be available in the area you want to display the image) and then calculate the resolution of the images based on that. If a user needs a smaller or larger version, Android will scale the image up or down, given your layout is correct.

From what you write, it seems to me like you're targeting *normal* screen sizes, so you can have something between 470dp x 320dp and 640dp x 480dp. To get regular pixels, you must think about the screen density of your users, refer [to a Question about dp/px conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656540/android-convert-px-to-dp-video-aspect-ratio) for details.