# How to move a button using dp?

Tags: android, button

I am trying to move a button via Script. Here is what it looks like:

```
   Handler handler2 = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            float y = chatButtonOne.getY();
            float yB = 40;
            float pxs = yB * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            chatButtonOne.setY(y - pxs);
            chatButtonOne2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }, 2000);
```

Now this (y - 40) is problematic in terms of different device sizes, so i am trying to use dp instead. Does anybody know how to do that?

Edit: This one here did the trick, i updated the original script i posted:

[stackoverflow.com/a/14921982/1987425](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14921982/1987425)

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/14921982/1987425

Comment: That's the one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the pixels to dp. You can achieve that with this:

```
public static int pixelToDps(Context context, int desiredDps) {
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density; //get device density
    int calculatedPixels = (int) (desiredDps * scale + 0.5f);  //The +0.5 rounds up to the nearest whole number if necessary. When converted to integer, everything after the decimal is simply cut off. The +0.5 ensures that the most "correct" integer is returned
    return calculatedPixels;
}
```

See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6656774/8490899

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `dp` to pixels using `TypedValue#applyDimension()`:

```
int pixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp,
                                             getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```