# How to calculate dp from pixels in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, resolution

I want to calculate `dp` from `px` programmatically. How to do it?
I get resolution from:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
ht = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
wt = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Comment: Do you know the physical dimension of the screen? 7" in diemeter for example.

Comment: Its annoying when its marked as a duplicate, but no link to the duplicate is attached to the duplicate notice.

Answer (score 402, accepted):

**All the answers here show a *dp->px* conversion rather than *px->dp*, which is what the OP asked for.**
Note that [`TypedValue.applyDimension`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#applyDimension%28int,%20float,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics%29) cannot be used to convert px->dp, for that you must use the method described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17880012/504611 (quoted below for convenience).

```
fun Context.dpToPx(dp: Int): Int {
    return (dp * resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()
}

fun Context.pxToDp(px: Int): Int {
    return (px / resources.displayMetrics.density).toInt()
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer: return px / (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / 160f)

Comment: @androiddeveloper, please explain why you think using densityDpi is better than density.

Comment: @SaQada Look at the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics#density :  "The logical density of the display", "This value does not exactly follow the real screen size" , "To obtain the current density for a specific display, use densityDpi" . However, now that I've tested both ways, both seem to work fine. Just try to prefer float or double instead of int, because int might lose some precision on some cases. For example, try to convert the height to dp and back to px on QVGA, and you will get 319 instead of 320.

Comment: `Resource.getSystem()` has no guarantee when multiple Displays exist.

Answer (score 56):

```
float ht_px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, ht, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
float wt_px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, wt, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Question is about "px -> dp" , but the code looks like "dp -> px" ?? (note the '_px' suffix in LHS )

Comment: This is converting the opposite way from question.

Comment: any way you can change first parameter to `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX` from  `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP` so as to convert `dp-> px`

Comment: @NullnVoid: That won't work. If you see the [docs for `TypedValue.applyDimension`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#applyDimension(int,%20float,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics)), it says: "Converts an unpacked complex data value holding a dimension to its final floating point value", i.e., the return value is always in px. So if you pass `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX` it will just do a px->px "conversion", which is to say, nothing.

Answer (score 39):

This should give you the conversion pixels -> dp:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
int dp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension( TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, myPixels, displaymetrics );
```

Comment: **What you're doing is a dp->px conversion.** [The docs for `TypedValue.applyDimension`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#applyDimension%28int,%20float,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics%29) say that the first argument is the unit to convert _from_, and the return value is the "complex floating point value multiplied by the appropriate metrics depending on its unit." `applyDimension` cannot be used to convert px->dp, for that you must do it as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17880012/504611

Comment: funny! Although it is not the real answer but it's still useful

Answer (score 2):

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        String str_ScreenSize = "The Android Screen is: "
                    + dm.widthPixels
                    + " x "
                    + dm.heightPixels;

        TextView mScreenSize = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.strScreenSize);
        mScreenSize.setText(str_ScreenSize);
```

can u cheeck it out..

or this may also help u

```
int value = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 
                     (float) 123.4, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```