# pixels within a specific portion of screen Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to calculate number of pixels in a specific portion of screen??  say i draw a circle and want to calculate no. of pixels inside the circle!

Comment: Have you seen this [**SO answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295986/how-to-calculate-dp-from-pixels-in-android-programmatically)?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor i know how to calculate no. if pixel of whole screen but i dun knw how to perform the same for a specific portion

Answer (score 1):

You can get the width and height of a view but it depends how you're drawing the circle. If you're drawing it on a Canvas you can calculate the area of the circle using:

```
area = Π x r(2)
```

All you need is the radius of the circle and use 3.1415927 as the value of Pi.

Comment: i had to discard the concept of area..bcoz by this method we cant calculate area of irregular figures

Comment: Are you drawing on a canvas?

Comment: yes..i am drawing on canvas

Comment: If you have a fixed background colour and the 'shape' you want to count the pixels of is a fixed colour you can export the canvas to a bitmap and then step through the value of each pixel. So, if the background is black, and you're drawing in red, count through all pixels and total the red pixels.

Comment: it solved half of the problem :) Thnxx :D

Comment: but what if the user draws an image on canvas and then we have to calculate the number of pixels

Answer (score 0):

Push the canvas to a bitmap then count the pixels:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View v) {
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
v.draw(c);
return b;
```

}

That will get you the bitmap, then step through each pixel and count the colour you're looking for:

```
for(int x = 0; x < b.getWidth(); x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < b.getHeight(); y++){
        int pixel = b.getPixel(x,y);
        int r = Color.red(pixel);
        int g = Color.green(pixel);
        int b = Color.blue(pixel);

        //test against your colour here and increment counter
    }
}
```

I don't have an IDE to hand so the code may be a bit rough but it will put you on the right lines.