# My Gradient colors is not the same on different screen sizes?

Tags: android

I don't understand why this happend, but I would like to know why and how to solve it. I want my gradient to look like in the Galaxy S7 picture for all devices or different screen sizes

[image]

**The code for Gradient:**

```
    textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fontcolorwhite);

    LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(60,-70,60,70, new int[]{Color.parseColor("#00a8d9"), Color.parseColor("#4244b8"), Color.parseColor("#f1328f"), Color.parseColor("#ee3031"), Color.parseColor("#fde92d"), Color.parseColor("#009e54")},null,
    Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    textView.getPaint().setShader(linearGradient);
```

Comment: Well, you are using absolute pixel values. Why not use `dp`.

Comment: Are the values in the parameters in pixels? @Shaishav

Comment: `TextView#getTextSize()`

Comment: @pskink What do you mean?

Comment: use this to get the text size

Comment: @pskink Allright. Where shall I use this textsize?

Comment: @pskink No Sir. I have read the documentation of the  `LinearGradient`and I can't really see where the textsize should be used

Comment: so what are the first 4 params of the ctor?

Comment: @pskink those are the angle, spread of the color and positioning of the whole gradient

Comment: "spread of the color" that's right, if you make it constant for different text sizes you will get the results you got in the picture above

Comment: Long story short: Settle on a `dp` value for your gradient and then use [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8295986/how-to-calculate-dp-from-pixels-in-android-programmatically) to get that `dp` in `px` and finally set it in the gradient above.

Comment: @pskink Are we talking about the same things? I'm talking about the hardcoded values he used for his gradient `(60,-70,60,70)`

Comment: @Shaishav Thanks! It works now!

Comment: @pskink Yes it worked

Answer (score 0):

Allright it now works perfect on all devices and screen size.

The end solution was to use dp instead of pixels and playing around with values till I got the right gradient:

```
    float px4 = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    float px5 = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, -17f, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    float px6 = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 15, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    float px7 = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18f, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());


    LinearGradient linearGradient = new LinearGradient(px4, px5, px6, px7, new int[]{Color.parseColor("#00a8d9"), Color.parseColor("#4244b8"), Color.parseColor("#f1328f"), Color.parseColor("#ee3031"), Color.parseColor("#fde92d"), Color.parseColor("#009e54")}, null,
            Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
    fontcolorpickerbtn.getPaint().setShader(linearGradient);
```