# Generating Linear Layout Views Dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, android-linearlayout, android-spinner

My goal is to generate the layout of a view in Android Studios dynamically. The ultimate goal is to dynamically generate the following view

number - name - role

all on one line.

This is the current background code in Android Studio, which is currently setting the layout as follows

number
name
role

CODE

```
private void GenerateLayout()
{

    llisroles = findViewById(R.id.llRoles);

    for (int x = 0; x < num_players; x++)
    {

        TextView number = new TextView(this);
        EditText name = new EditText(this);
        Spinner role = new Spinner(this);
        //number.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //name.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        number.setText(names_players[x]);
        name.setText("");

        llisroles.addView (number);
        llisroles.addView(name);
        llisroles.addView(role);

    }



}
```

Comment: And your error/problem/question is?

Comment: To add views dinamically you nee to set the width and height of the views using a LayoutParams instance which in your case would be a LinearLayout.LayoutParams. The explanation is similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577994/with-framelayout-as-root-layout-add-view-on-top-of-another-one-with-offset-of/52578810#52578810

Comment: What's with the loop anyway, do you want to create a list of horizontal linear layouts?