# Android: How to maximize PreferenceFragment width (or get rid of margin)?

Tags: android, preference

[image: Android Settings Screenshot]

[image: FragmentsBC Screenshot]

If you look at either Android Settings screenshot or [FragmentsBC](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/FragmentsBC) screenshot, there are margin in PreferenceFragment. How can you get rid of it?

I tried making PreferenceFragment width to fill_parent, but no luck.

Comment: Similar question answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509369/android-how-to-get-remove-margin-padding-in-preference-screen

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution to this.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    if(v != null) {
        ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    }
    return v;
}
```

You can set padding by using: setPadding();

Comment: hey @jclova, I am facing same problem as urs. 
Here is link of it :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509369/android-how-to-get-remove-margin-padding-in-preference-screen/18509566?noredirect=1#18509566
Acutally I am not creating any custom layout for preference screen. Simply having checkboxpreference in layout,though it is setting any
margin to left. Do you have any idea where I am going wrong please help.

Comment: Keep in mind that the padding amounts are in Px. You will probably want to convert them from dp to px before setting

Comment: Any way to override this in xml.

Comment: For me "v" always returns null (super.onCreateView(...))

Comment: Worked flawlessly with Android 4.3, I was getting ready to forget about it.

Comment: getListView().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0); for android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.

Answer (score 10):

Just an addition to this; the accepted answer did not work for me because the `ListView` itself does not have any padding set, it is set on the parent view (usually a `LinearLayout`).  So instead, the following was necessary:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)lv.getParent();
parent.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better adding `lv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);`? For me @jclova's answer does work, but I'll set both padding of `lv` and `lv.getParent()`, to deal with untested devices. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

`getListView().setPadding(left, top, right, bottom)`

Make sure to call it after your view has been created (not `onCreate`).

Keep in mind that the `int` you pass in is in `pixels`, not `dp`.  To convert from `dp to pixels` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6327095/1747491).

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me. I invoked this in my `PreferenceActivity`'s `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 3):

The answers here didn't work for me. However, this one did:

*source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53402144/9026710*

In your PreferenceScreen add this line:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

add this line in PreferenceScreen and it's elements:

```
app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
```

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="key1"
        android:title="title1" />
    <SwitchPreference
        app:iconSpaceReserved="false"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="@string/pref_wakeup"
        android:title="key2" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do in the onResume override:

```
    // Fix PreferenceFragment's padding...
    int paddingSize = 0;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14)
    {
        paddingSize = (int) (-32 * CLS_Gfx.scale);
    }
    else
    {
        paddingSize = (int) (-16 * CLS_Gfx.scale);
    }

    final View v = getView();

    v.setPadding(paddingSize, 0, paddingSize, 0);
```

Comment: This is working perfectly for me. Even android:icon="@null" was not making any changes but your solution works. Thank u so much for great solution. I think this should be an accepted answer.

Comment: @Smeet I'm glad it helped you!

Answer (score 2):

There's more elegant solution, at least for PreferenceFragmentCompat, to define the padding in a theme. Assume we have our activity set a android:theme="@style/PreferenceTheme"

```
   <style name="PreferenceTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
       <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/MyPreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
   </style>

   <style name="MyPreferenceThemeOverlay" parent="PreferenceThemeOverlay">
        <item name="preferenceFragmentListStyle">@style/MyPreferenceFragmentListStyle</item>
   </style>

   <style name="MyPreferenceFragmentListStyle" parent="@style/PreferenceFragmentList">
       <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
       <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
   </style>
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me. Still see paddings when using PreferenceFragmentCompat. Also, I dont get any warnings or errors, but <item name="preferenceTheme"> doesnt even exist (autocomplete doesnt work)

Comment: @qkx the fact autocomplete does not work does not mean the attribute doesn't exist; `preferenceTheme` attribute does exist (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32073430/639183). So most likely you have some issues with setup (perhaps with support library or its version?)

Comment: I am using latest version (28.0.0) and I literally copy pasted your code and applied this style. It really doesnt work at all :) And it cant - because problem is not padding, problem is that compat preference always reserve spacing for icon. Thats the root of the problem, not padding. So you have to set preserveIconSpacing to false - but in code, programatically (in xml it doest work). Thats a real solution :) I also found it on some other questions and I can confirm it works perfectly.

Comment: Ok, it can't work, still it works for me and at least 2 upvoted users ;) You copy-pasted the solution, but there's no setup to copy-paste, so my comment is still applicable: we may have different setup, that's why it works for me but doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set your own adapter.
That way you have more flexibility and it's more robust against changes.

See [that other answer about custom header adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771109/is-it-possible-to-customize-preference-header-layout)

Answer (score -1):

When you do the preference activity with a fragment, here is the solution that I used:

```
public class T2DPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
            new T2DPreferenceFragment()).commit();
}

public static class T2DPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.server_screen_preference);
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)lv.getParent();
        parent.setPadding(0, 100, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: No comment when down voting?