# how to add margin/padding to preference screen

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-settings

This is my code:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="title" >
        <Preference
            android:layout="@layout/custom_preference_layout"
            android:title="@string/settings_rateUsOnGooglePlay" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

It is not possible to simply specify a margin/padding in the PreferenceScreen element.
How do i add Margin/Padding to the preference screen?

Answer (score 7):

**Nov. 2019 Update:**
There is a solution, contrary to the first answer from years ago.

**Option 1:**
If you are inflating your `PreferenceScreen` as a fragment into a `FrameLayout`, you can assign a dp value to `layout_marginTop` or `layout_marginBottom` like so.

```
        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp" />
```

**Option 2:**
Otherwise, you can access the `RecyclerView` object, (this contains the PreferenceScreen's items) in the fragment's `OnViewCreated` like this:

```
    // PreferenceFragment class
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        final RecyclerView rv = getListView(); // This holds the PreferenceScreen's items
        rv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 56); // (left, top, right, bottom)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot simply specify a padding/margin. It seems you need to either specify a custom layout or `android:icon="@null"` like in

[Android: How to adjust Margin/Padding in Preference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539786/android-how-to-adjust-margin-padding-in-preference)

Or you can try setting margin/padding programmatically like in

[Android: How to maximize PreferenceFragment width (or get rid of margin)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314845/android-how-to-maximize-preferencefragment-width-or-get-rid-of-margin)