# Margin on PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

Sorry by my English...

I have a PreferenceActivity with 2 headers

```
<header
    android:fragment="com.example.example.fragments.FragmentPreferences"
    android:title="@string/tag_preferences_title_noticia" >
    <extra
        android:name="resource"
        android:value="preferences_noticia" />
</header> 

<header
    android:fragment="com.example.example.fragments.Prefs_FAQ"
    android:title="@string/tag_preferences_title_faq"
    android:id="@+id/pref_title_faq" >
    <extra
        android:name="resource"
        android:value="preferences_faq" />
</header>
```

My Prefs_FAQ is a PreferenceFragment

```
public class Prefs_FAQ extends PreferenceFragment  {  

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.prefs_faq, container, false);
}
```

But when the layout prefs_faq layout is inflated i want that have not margin

I tried some codes but none works

Answer (score 0):

This is likely what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9397408/3238938
Grabs the ListView using super.onCreateView() and calls setPadding() on that view.