# Preference Activity white margin on large screens

Tags: android, android-layout, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to change the preference list background colour which works fine for smaller devices, but leaves an ugly white margin on tablets. While looking for solutions I read that on larger devices the preference list view is placed in a fragment.

Any ideas on how I can remove it? Do I just need to work out how to set the parents background colour?

Not allowed to post images yet, so here's the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OuT3.png

AppPreferenceActivity.java:

```
 @override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // ---load the preferences from an XML file---
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.myapppreferences);

    int[] colour = getIntent().getExtras().getIntArray("mColour");
    getListView().setBackgroundColor(
            Color.rgb(colour[0], colour[1], colour[2]));

    // Set theme & colour
    setTheme(R.style.PreferencesTheme);
    getActionBar().setTitle("Preferences");
    setIcon();`
```

themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="PreferencesTheme">
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#fff</item>


</style>
```

myapppreferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<PreferenceCategory android:title="Display Settings" >
    <ListPreference
        android:dialogTitle="Colour..."
        android:defaultValue="Red"
        android:entries="@array/colourEntries"
        android:entryValues="@array/colourValues"
        android:key="pref_colour"
        android:summary="Choose a default background colour..."
        android:title="App Background Colour" >
    </ListPreference>
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="Reminder Settings" >
    <ListPreference
        android:dialogTitle="Remind me..."
        android:defaultValue="The day before"
        android:entries="@array/dayRemindEntries"
        android:entryValues="@array/dayRemindValues"
        android:key="pref_days_before"
        android:summary="Remind me..."
        android:title="Default reminder..." >
    </ListPreference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting android:windowBackground instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addPreferencesFromResource` method is deprecated in API 11 and higher. Try to use a `PreferenceFragment` and override onCreateView like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    if(v != null) {
        ListView lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    }
    return v;
}
```

This code is taken from this response:
[Android: How to maximize PreferenceFragment width (or get rid of margin)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314845/android-how-to-maximize-preferencefragment-width-or-get-rid-of-margin)