# New Preference support library incorrect theme at runtime

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-preferences, preferencefragment

I'm trying to use the new Preference v14 Support library. To give the preferences a material style, I use the following style on my Activity:

```
<style name="PreferenceTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
</style>
```

That works fine. My problem is that when I add new Preferences at runtime, they get inflated using an old theme. Here's a screenshot of the result:

[image: WTF]

As you can see, the first preference, added via XML, has the new Material style, while the others don't.

Do you have any hint on how to solve the problem?

**EDIT**
Here's an example of code I use to add the Preference at Runtime:

```
import android.support.v7.preference.ListPreference;

for (...) {
        final ListPreference p = new ListPreference(getActivity());
        p.setTitle(name);
        p.setSummary(langname);
        p.setEntryValues(langEntryValues);
        p.setEntries(langDisplayValues);
        p.setDialogTitle(R.string.select_language);

        category.addPreference(p);
    }
```

PS: The same behavior occurs with `android.support.v7.preference.Preference`

Comment: What's your device's API level? Also, could you post the code you use to add new preferences?

Comment: I've tested this under API 22 and 23. Same behavior. See updated answer for code.

Comment: I see, looking into the issue right now...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem, you're facing, is related to `Context` and how its theming works. Your code retrieves a context by passing `getActivity()` to the constructor, however, this is not the context you want. Here's the solution that applies the correct styles:

```
final Context ctx = getPreferenceManager().getContext();

for (...) {
    final ListPreference p = new ListPreference(ctx);
    // [...]

    category.addPreference(p);
}
```

### Explanation

Here's `PreferenceFragmentCompat`'s `onCreate(...)` method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    this.getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(attr.preferenceTheme, tv, true);
    int theme = tv.resourceId;
    if(theme <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Must specify preferenceTheme in theme");
    } else {
        this.mStyledContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(this.getActivity(), theme);
        this.mPreferenceManager = new PreferenceManager(this.mStyledContext);
        // [...]

        this.onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState, rootKey);
    }
}
```

The important lines:

```
this.getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(attr.preferenceTheme, tv, true);
int theme = tv.resourceId;
```

Here the `preferenceTheme` is being retrieved from the Activity's theme. If it exists (i.e. `theme` is not 0), *PFC* (`PreferenceFragmentCompat`) creates a new theme wrapper which will contain the styling infos:

```
this.mStyledContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(this.getActivity(), theme);
```

Using this styled context, the *PFC* can now create the `PreferenceManager`:

```
this.mPreferenceManager = new PreferenceManager(this.mStyledContext);
```

This *PFC*'s *root* style is now the `preferenceTheme` which contains all the different sub-styles (`preferenceStyle` for example).

The problem with your solution is that the `Preference` class is looking for a `preferenceStyle` attribute in the contructor-passed context. However, it's only defined in your `preferenceTheme`, not in the Activity's theme.

Comment: I'll add a little more explanation, just wanted to give you a quick fix.

Comment: No problem, added this interesting case to my [support preference-v7 bugfix project](https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix).