# SwitchPreferenceCompat looking different when added to XML vs created programmatically

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-preferences, android-preference-v14

In a `PreferenceFragment`, I have a `SwitchPreferenceCompat` added via XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="cat 1">

        <SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:key="pref_1"
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:title="from xml"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:key="pref_cat_1"
        android:title="cat 2"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

and one added programmatically:

```
PreferenceGroup preferenceGroup = (PreferenceGroup) findPreference("pref_cat_1");

SwitchPreferenceCompat switchPreference = new SwitchPreferenceCompat(getActivity());
switchPreference.setWidgetLayoutResource(android.support.v7.preference.R.layout.preference_widget_switch_compat);
switchPreference.setTitle("programmatically");
switchPreference.setChecked(true);
switchPreference.setDefaultValue(true);

switchPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(final Preference preference, final Object newValue) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), newValue.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;
    }
});

preferenceGroup.addPreference(switchPreference);
```

On the screen they look different (fontsize):

[image]

I tried omitting the line

```
switchPreference.setWidgetLayoutResource(android.support.v7.preference.R.layout.preference_widget_switch_compat);
```

but then the Switch button becomes invisible.

How can I make them look the same?

Test project can be found [on Github](https://github.com/fweigl/PrefThrowAway/tree/branch_two) (branch_two).

Comment: Do you actually wrap the `SwitchPreferenceCompat` in the `PreferenceCategory` just like the one above?

Comment: `PreferenceScreen` also has its compat brother, declare it in `xml` instead of original `PreferenceScreen`.

Comment: When I use `Compat 25.2.0` they look exactly the same.

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen Sorry, forgot to push my changes. If you checkout branch_two again, you will see the difference.

Comment: @azizbekian There is no PreferenceScreenCompat.

Comment: Yes, but there is `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen`

Comment: @azizbekian I see, sorry, yeah. But using that doesn't seem to solve my font size problem. Please mind, I updated the test project, actually using SwitchPreferenceCompat (had used SwitchPreference before).

Comment: I switched to CheckBoxPreference - it doesn't have this problem.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the same problem of using the wrong context to create the new Preference. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32457928/2644098) for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

When you inflate preferences from XML they use the `preferenceTheme` you specified in your app theme.

When you created the preference programmatically you used plain activity theme.

If you use the correctly themed Context it will work as expected:

```
new SwitchPreferenceCompat(getPreferenceManager().getContext());
```