# Android - change preference category color on marshmallow

Tags: android, preference, preference-v7

I want to change v7 `PreferenceCategory` text and divider color.

I have recently viewed this question:
[PreferenceFragmentCompat requires preferenceTheme to be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070670/preferencefragmentcompat-requires-preferencetheme-to-be-set)
and I've added this to my style:

```
<style name="AppThemeNoActionBar.ListSeparatorTextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/website_main</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">2dp</item>
</style>
```

And it works only on Kitkat, I have checked on marshmallow and it look like that:
[image]
(gray title instead of blue)

How can i change this?