# Remove dividers from preference-v7:24.1.0

Tags: android, preference

After upgrading to `support:preference-v7:24.1.1'` my preference screen changed from this

[image]

to this

[image]

Is this some king of bug or that's the new preference screen of Android?Is there a way to go back to the old style while targeting SDK 24?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is new appearence of preference screen. But you can read this article to know about how to go back to the "old style": 
[PreferenceFragmentCompat requires preferenceTheme to be set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070670/preferencefragmentcompat-requires-preferencetheme-to-be-set)