# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must specify preferenceTheme in theme

Tags: android

I am trying to load a PreferenceFragment (PreferenceFragmentCompat) in an application running on API 16, but every time I attempt to load the fragment I get the following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must specify preferenceTheme in theme

The fragment loads just fine in API levels 21 and up. I've tried using this library https://github.com/Gericop/Android-Support-Preference-V7-Fix, but it's still not working.

Comment: What have you set as `theme`? The error says you need to set a theme of type `PreferenceTheme`.

Comment: I managed to fix it. The problem was my activity that was loading the fragment didn't have the theme set.

`<activity android:name=".controllers.MainActivity"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base"/>`

Comment: Write an answer and close the thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix it. The problem was my activity that was loading the fragment didn't have the theme set.

`<activity android:name=".controllers.MainActivity"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base" />`