# Fragment Must specify preferenceTheme in theme onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to figure out why I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must specify preferenceTheme in theme
at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onCreate(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:210)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2177)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager
```

When trying to run my PreferenceFragmentCompat
This is the above class code:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

public SettingsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static SettingsFragment newInstance() {
    SettingsFragment fragment = new SettingsFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_preferences, rootKey);
}

}
```

This is the activity's manifest declaration that shows the fragment

```
<activity
        android:name=".active_minutes_screen.view.ActiveMinutesActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Code that shows the fragment in the above MainActivity

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, HistoryFragment.newInstance());
ft.commit();
```

Theme that I am applying via the MainActivity

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PreferenceFragmentCompat requires preferenceTheme to be set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070670/preferencefragmentcompat-requires-preferencetheme-to-be-set)

Comment: @Panther I did the proposed solutions there. That is why I opened my question

Comment: Your code does not show any `preferenceTheme` in your theme.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I did included the style that I am applying. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Thanks to the solution that @Panther suggested. All I had to do is to add this line `<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>`
to my Application Theme and not just the theme of the individual activity that is showing my PreferenceFragment like that:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

Alternatively you can use

`<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>`

to achieve modern material look.

Comment: Make sure you are adding preferenceTheme to the right style which is set as theme for your activity https://stackoverflow.com/a/40736138/1572286