# App crash Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, preferencescreen

My app crashes every time I try to access the settings menu. I am taking a course through udacity for android development. The app runs fine when I load the AVD, and it does not give me any errors. I am thinking it has to do with how I set up the xml or the java activity of the menu. I tried using the code answer provided for us on the lesson but the app still crashes. I would really appreciate if somebody can help me with this issue. I am new to android programming. Here are the files associated with the app.

here is the logcat

```
03-05 12:53:14.514 11791-11791/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-05 12:53:14.551 11791-11797/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
03-05 12:53:14.551 11791-11797/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
03-05 12:53:14.688 11791-11791/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.android.example.sunshineapp-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.android.example.sunshineapp-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-05 12:53:14.903 11791-11791/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.android.example.sunshineapp-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.android.example.sunshineapp-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-05 12:53:14.955 11791-11791/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.android.example.sunshineapp-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.android.example.sunshineapp-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-05 12:53:15.004 11791-11791/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.android.example.sunshineapp-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.android.example.sunshineapp-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-05 12:53:15.059 11791-11791/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.android.example.sunshineapp-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.android.example.sunshineapp-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-05 12:53:15.110 11791-11791/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.android.example.sunshineapp-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.android.example.sunshineapp-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-05 12:53:15.162 11791-11791/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.android.example.sunshineapp-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.android.example.sunshineapp-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-05 12:53:15.213 11791-11791/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.android.example.sunshineapp-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.android.example.sunshineapp-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-05 12:53:15.272 11791-11791/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.android.example.sunshineapp-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.android.example.sunshineapp-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-05 12:53:15.324 11791-11791/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.android.example.sunshineapp-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.android.example.sunshineapp-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-05 12:53:15.379 11791-11791/? W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.android.example.sunshineapp-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.android.example.sunshineapp-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
03-05 12:53:15.380 11791-11791/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.android.example.sunshineapp-2/lib/arm
03-05 12:53:15.398 11791-11791/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
03-05 12:53:15.401 11791-11791/? V/InstantRun: Starting server socket listening for package com.android.example.sunshineapp on android.net.LocalSocketAddress@75de48c
03-05 12:53:15.402 11791-11791/? V/InstantRun: Started server for package com.android.example.sunshineapp
03-05 12:53:15.628 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
03-05 12:53:15.719 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp D/PhoneWindowEx: [PWEx][generateLayout] setLGNavigationBarColor : colors=0xffe9ebee
03-05 12:53:15.719 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/PhoneWindow: [setLGNavigationBarColor] color=0x ffe9ebee
03-05 12:53:15.949 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp D/MainActivity: onCreate: registering preference changed listener
03-05 12:53:15.994 11791-11885/com.android.example.sunshineapp D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: false
03-05 12:53:15.999 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp D/PhoneWindow: notifyNavigationBarColor, color=0x: ffe9ebee, token: android.view.ViewRootImplAO$WEx@f0a0e16
03-05 12:53:16.000 11791-11884/com.android.example.sunshineapp V/NetworkUtils: URL: https://andfun-weather.udacity.com/staticweather?q=Mountain%20View%2C%20CA%2094043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=14
03-05 12:53:16.004 11791-11884/com.android.example.sunshineapp D/libc: skt_base:0, kt_base:0, mptcp_enabled:0, socks_enabled:0, wifi_connected:1
03-05 12:53:16.004 11791-11884/com.android.example.sunshineapp D/libc: skt_base:0, kt_base:0, mptcp_enabled:0, socks_enabled:0, wifi_connected:1
03-05 12:53:16.133 11791-11885/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-05 12:53:16.147 11791-11885/com.android.example.sunshineapp D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000
03-05 12:53:16.188 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
03-05 12:53:16.198 11791-11884/com.android.example.sunshineapp D/libc: skt_base:0, kt_base:0, mptcp_enabled:0, socks_enabled:0, wifi_connected:1
03-05 12:53:16.310 11791-11885/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0xb8314640), client(52), share_fd(50)
03-05 12:53:16.443 11791-11885/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0xb831cff0), client(52), share_fd(53)
03-05 12:53:16.451 11791-11885/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0xb840dbd8), client(52), share_fd(55)
03-05 12:53:17.142 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@8436731 time:153533026
03-05 12:53:18.549 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
03-05 12:53:18.633 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
03-05 12:53:18.649 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/AudioManagerEx: AudioManagerEx created
03-05 12:53:18.781 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/ListPopupWindow: Could not find method setEpicenterBounds(Rect) on PopupWindow. Oh well.
03-05 12:53:18.926 11791-11885/com.android.example.sunshineapp D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000
03-05 12:53:18.982 11791-11885/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0xb84d1348), client(52), share_fd(60)
03-05 12:53:19.027 11791-11885/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0xb83098c8), client(52), share_fd(62)
03-05 12:53:19.047 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp V/ViewRootImpl: Contents drawing finished : PopupWindow:1c994ca
03-05 12:53:19.054 11791-11885/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/[MALI][Gralloc]: [+]r_hnd(0xb7f94d18), client(52), share_fd(65)
03-05 12:53:19.710 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
03-05 12:53:19.811 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
03-05 12:53:19.880 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp D/[AOP]Intent: Intent Private Mode Enable
03-05 12:53:19.881 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.android.example.sunshineapp time:153535765
03-05 12:53:19.990 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp D/PhoneWindowEx: [PWEx][generateLayout] setLGNavigationBarColor : colors=0xffe9ebee
03-05 12:53:19.990 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp I/PhoneWindow: [setLGNavigationBarColor] color=0x ffe9ebee
03-05 12:53:20.057 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-05 12:53:20.120 11791-11791/com.android.example.sunshineapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.android.example.sunshineapp, PID: 11791
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.example.sunshineapp/com.android.example.sunshineapp.Settings}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
                                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                                     at com.android.example.sunshineapp.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:23)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6279)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
                                                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class fragment
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                     at com.android.example.sunshineapp.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:23) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6279) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must specify preferenceTheme in theme
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat.onCreate(PreferenceFragmentCompat.java:211)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2339)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1377)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1640)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1896)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3673)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:338)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:39)
                                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:754)
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                                     at com.android.example.sunshineapp.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:23) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6279) 
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: What is the error you get? "It crashes" is not very useful to us.

Comment: check the logs when the app crashes!

Comment: Can you post the output of Logcat, when the crash happens?

Comment: It loads fine when i run the AVD. Its when its in my phone and i go to click the settings menu. It says unfortunately sunshine app has stopped.

Comment: post your logcat error and if you don't know how, then follow the steps when your application crash.
-> On Downside in android studio 3.0.1 you can See "LogCat" Tab. So When you click at that menu you can see your errors and you can scroll up or scroll down for the error. The errors will be shown in RED Color.

Comment: I uploaded the logcat

Comment: @mountis you need to upload settings activity xml

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in manifest. Often people forget to add activity there. In Udacity (I assume there is a Vizualizer app) there is in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/action_settings"
    android:parentActivityName=".VisualizerActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".VisualizerActivity" />
</activity>
```

Comment: @mountis but it was a problem too. without this lines in manifest you'd receive another error.

Comment: thank you I added it. did you see the logcat. there were many errors

Comment: I figured out what the problem was. I was missing a preference theme. I found this answer on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772442/fragment-must-specify-preferencetheme-in-theme-oncreate

Comment: @mountis you can vote for my answer as a part-right (or I can to add another part of right answer)