# AndroidX Preferences exception: "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am trying to add a settings activity to my app as described in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings but after adding initial implementation, when my settings activity is loaded I get a "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity." exception.

[Fragment Must specify preferenceTheme in theme onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772442/fragment-must-specify-preferencetheme-in-theme-oncreate)
[You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

According to  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/archive/androidx this issue should not occur as of 1.0.0-rc01 androidX release and yet I am experiencing it.

as workarounds i tried to hardcode the theme for the settings activity in the activity's xml layout file, and also tried to add a preferenceTheme item to my app's styles.xml. none worked.

```java
/* settings activity + fragment */

public class SettingsPrefActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = SettingsPrefActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // load settings fragment

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new MainPreferenceFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    public static class MainPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_main, rootKey);
        }
}
```

My styles.xml:

```xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

to clarify I also tried specifically adding the following which didn't resolve the issue.

```xml
<item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
```

Comment: your problem is with your styles.xml file, this link you posted should be your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Comment: thanks. problem was with the manifest not the styles.xml. but your direction of that thread helped me figure that out.

Comment: no problem, happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

as @a_local_nobody suggested i went back to that linked thread and read it more thoroughly. turns out i was overriding the activity's theme in the app's manifest :(
cleared that and the activity renders properly. 
Thanks!