# Must specify preferenceTheme in theme occurred even after including it

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-preferences

I have a `MainActivity.cs` which inflates a fragment `SettingsFragment.cs` with `Test.axml`. The preferences definition is inside `preference_screen.xml`. I'm gettings this error while deplyoing:

```
Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Must specify preferenceTheme in theme occurred
```

So the obvious reasons is that there's no preferenceTheme specified in `styles.xml`. However, even after including this in my styles-file, the program still stops inside the `onCreate()`-method with the same error.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
  <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
</style>
```

Here's the other files:

**SettingsFragment.cs**:

```
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using SupportFragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;
using PreferenceTest.Fragments;
using Android.Graphics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using System;
using Android.Support.V7.Preferences;

namespace PreferenceTest.Fragments
{
    public class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat 
    {

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        public override void OnCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, string rootKey)
        {
            AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Layout.preference_screen);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // return our custom view for this fragment
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Test, container, false);


            return view;
        }



    }
}
```

**Test.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/home_layout">

</RelativeLayout>
```

**preference_screen.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <PreferenceCategory
      android:key="setting_title_title_category"
      android:title="Title options">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:id="@+id/setting_title_show_id"
        android:key="setting_title_show"
        android:title="Show Main Title"
        android:summary="Show/hide MainPage title" />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="setting_title_text"
        android:title="Set Main Title"
        android:summary="Change MainPage title"
        android:dialogTitle="Change Title"
        android:dialogMessage="Change title please..."/>

  </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**An overview of the NuGet packages:**

- Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable     {23.2.1}
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Design          {23.2.1}
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v14.Preference  {23.2.1}
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v4              {23.2.1}
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat    {23.2.1}
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Preference   {23.2.1}
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView {23.2.1}
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable {23.2.1}

***Any ideas on why? I highly appreciate any input on why it might be crashing.***

Comment: There is a similar problem, please refer to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070670/preferencefragmentcompat-requires-preferencetheme-to-be-set)

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT As I already mentioned in my post, I tried most of the suggested solutions on Stackoverflow (including the one you referred to), but none of them worked.