# Preference Tag Extra Padding In Android Pre Lolllipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, preference

I'm having a problem with my `Preference` in pre-L device. There is an extra padding/ margin that took place. I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314845/android-how-to-maximize-preferencefragment-width-or-get-rid-of-margin) but doesn't work. The 1st picture is pre-L and the other below is running Android L.

[image: Sample][image: L]

Here's my xml layouts: `activity_settings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/layout_settings"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<!--<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android.R.id.list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_container"/>--> </RelativeLayout>
```

`SettingsActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    //TOOL BAR
    setUpToolbar();
    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,settingsFragment,"Settings");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

**Is there any alternative way of eliminating this extra padding?**

Note: Target - 15 API to 23 API