# Wrong icon margins on standard preferencefragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I am creating a preference screen in Android using all standard layouts. But earlier I have been messing around with the code for fixing an earlier issue and now the preference icons won't center as per the normal margins. I have checked all my code and there is no references to icon margins or paddings. Can I have messed up in the stock layout files?

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwc7y.png)

As you can see the category title and the preference titles are fine. It is only the icon that is misplaced.

I have tried this [Android: How to maximize PreferenceFragment width (or get rid of margin)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314845/android-how-to-maximize-preferencefragment-width-or-get-rid-of-margin/9397408#9397408) but it changes the entire `PreferenceFragment` and not only the icons.

Comment: It's not the icon, it's the item TextView that has left margin or padding.

Comment: I am not sure of that. If you compare with the stock preference. the category title and the icon have the same left space. https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_11/assets/0B6Okdz75tqQsOEdqZHpWZHNKaXM/patterns_settings_subscreen3.png