# Convert Pixel value into dp value

Tags: android

I am able to find the screen width using `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()`. Now I want to know how can I get value in `dp` from the value that I got which is in pixel. For example, suppose I got a width of the screen using this code:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
```

Now the `width` I got is in pixel, how do I convert it into `dp`.

Please help me to solve this out. I have seen in the android documentation but don't get to know how to implement it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting pixels to dp in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp-in-android)

Comment: @PareshMayani I have used the following formula for getting dp values from pixels. Can u please check it whether the formula is right or not int widthDPI = (int) (screenWidthPx / (logicalDensity + 0.5));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert dp values to pixels u can use following formula:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
float logicalDensity = metrics.density;
int px = (int) (dp * logicalDensity + 0.5);
```

*To get dp from pixels, divide the density into the pixel value rather than multiply.*

Comment: Actually in my case i want to convert pixel value to dp. And here how can i find the logicalDensity

Comment: then divide density by pixel value

Comment: Ok for correction i want to ask u...is this the right way to do for converting pixel value in dp int dp = (int) (width / (logicalDensity + 0.5)); Actually my width is 240 px and in result i got 192 dp is it right.

Comment: Imran, Why there should be + 0.5

Comment: @PavankumarVijapur then what will be the syntax.

Comment: What is the `metrics` variable here: `.getMetrics(` **metrics** `)`? I am getting `Illegal self reference` in Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

For example: create new `dimens.xml` in your `res/values` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="dim_5dp">5dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Then in your activity:

```
int pixels = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dim_5dp);
```

The benefit is [getDimensionPixelSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimensionPixelSize%28int%29) takes care of zero-size, it returns at least 1 pixel in that case.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use pixel density of your screen to convert between actual pixels and dp. This is described in [Android developer portal/guide here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#dips-pels). Take a look

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way is to use TypedValue.

```
  public static float pxToDp(Context context, float pixel) {
            return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, pixel, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
  }
```