# Android Screen Resolutions px and dp

Tags: android, resolution, pixel

For icons they are: 
36x36px
48x48px
72x72px
96x96px

And for screen sizes they are:
426x320
470x320
640x480
960x720

But I think I might have heard from the website that those screen sizes are in dp. I know that "dp" is dimmensional pixels. But my question is: When I go into Adobe Illustrator to create a background for the small screen size (426x320), should I use the unit PIXELS or do I need to convert those numbers to something else.

Comment: what do you call a "background for small screen size". A picture to put in background? Or a drawable resource (which then should be better a 9-patch)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

dp is not "dimmensional pixels" . it's "(density) independent pixels" (see [**here**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) and [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device-independent_pixel)) . they are based on the density of the device , not the resolution .

for example , for application icons , it's always 48 dp , since on mdpi(160 dpi) , 48 dp== 48 pixels .
therefore , on hdpi (240 dpi) , it's 48*1.5=72 pixels , on ldpi(120 dpi) it's 48*0.75=36 , and on xhdpi (320 dpi) it's 48*2=96 pixels .

if you wish to have the best results of showing images, create the images based on the dpi level of your target devices. this means that for each dpi level , you need to create an image best suited for it , and put it on the correct folder in the "res" folder .

this could take x4 times , and you might simply prefer having a single file instead . it all depends on the result that you see. if you can't tell the difference of your image on an mdpi device and xhdpi device , you don't have to make any changes.

for more information on android graphical design , read this:
http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Comment: What are Nine-Patch Drawables?

Comment: they are images that you can choose which part of them (horizontal and vertical ) can be multiplied and which should retain their look. you can also choose what part of them is used for the content itself (for the text) . for more info : http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/ . you have a tool that comes with the sdk manager to create such images , which is called "draw9patch" .

Comment: @androiddeveloper I have a question about this, if you don't mind. If a manufacturer say the screen resolution is `1,280×768`, how can I then convert this to `dp`? I want my application to support the minimum width of `768px`, the same as the Nexus 4, but I need to provide it in `dp`.

Comment: @ClassA Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9563438/878126

Comment: "it's "(density) dependent pixels" " - No, the unit is called density-independent pixels (see: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

Comment: @SOUser Correct. Was a typo. Even written about it on Wikipedia. I've updated my answer now. Thank you. Have +1 for this.