# Drawing a view on different screen resolution

Tags: android, canvas, android-view, ondraw

I am trying to drawing a rectangle view in my application, but its looks different in different devices having different screen resolution. Any idea how to draw same size of view in all different resolution devises. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [documentation (Supporting multiple Screen Sizes)](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html):

Multiply your dimensions with `scale`

```
// Get the screen's density scale
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Sherif elKhatib, can you give a example

Comment: check the answer of prasobh on this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp-in-android