# Android ListView Item - View in listview item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

When I use a view in listview item, it doesn't show the view for the item when I use `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. If i set some value for the layout_height like 50dp, it works usually.
The problem is that I cant set a specific value for height, I need it all the height.

Anybody knows how to solve that problem?

Edit:

Listview item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/lv_main_view_account"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/lv_main_view_category"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/lv_main_view_category"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lv_main_view_account"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lv_main_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lv_main_value"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lv_main_local"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/lv_main_value"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lv_main_date"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lv_main_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` ? Anyways, if you want one item to populate the whole `ListView` then why do you need the `ListView` in the first place? You could just use that inner item

Comment: if you want that a view fill the whole item just declare it as the parent in layout, don't use Linear or relative layout. just the item. and use wrap_content.

Comment: The view is just a item of a lot of item of this view...

Comment: wrap_content, match_parent, fill parent doesn't not work. When I use some this value, it like to use visibility="invisible". When I use some value like 50dp, it works...

Comment: you need get screen height and set that to view dynamically, you can't set via xml

Comment: what is your listview layout, can you post it?

Comment: xml posted is the layout of listview item. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

It is not going to work at all. If you really want to do that you can set the height of the item inside your ListView's adapter.

[Getting screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252067/how-do-i-get-the-screensize-programmatically-in-android)

[Setting the height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911011/android-set-imageview-layout-height-programmatically)