# how to draw lines with drawLine method in multiple density screens

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have read many posts about my problem but I haven't found a solution. I'm going crazy!

I use the following code, in the main Class, to get the pulse on the screen:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        x = (int) event.getX();
        y = (int) event.getY();
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            view.draw(canvas);
            view.invalidate();
        break;
}
```

view is:
`DrawView view;`

and DrawView is an inner class:

```
public class DrawView extends LinearLayout
```

and in the DrawView class I have the next two methods to draw the line:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    }

@Override
public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawLine((int) 0,(int) 0,(int) x,(int) y, paint);
    }
```

My problem is how to properly draw lines on screens with different screen densities.
I've tried with:

```
float d = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
```

But I still can't paint the lines correctly.

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Converting dip to px: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp-in-android

Comment: but with the method event.getX() and event.getY() you get the px,no??and the drawLine() method uses px units, I think. Or I get dips units in the event.getX() method and then I have to convert this to px and finally I can draw? Thanks for your answer