# how to set width of widget programatically in dips

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm adding a widget to a layout dynamically.
I need to set the widget width as 100 through code like the below :

Width = 100;
How can I convert the above given value to dps in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 * This method converts device specific pixels to density independent pixels.
 * 
 * @param px A value in px (pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into db
 * @param context Context to get resources and device specific display metrics
 * @return A float value to represent dp equivalent to px value
 */
public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return dp;
}
```

Credit: [Converting pixels to dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp-in-android)