# Android set LeftMargin doesn't work on some devices

Tags: android, layoutparams

I've coded a `Drag and drop` behaviour for my `Android` application. So far it works perfectly on my `HTC One` and on my `Samsung S3`. Basically, it just sets the `leftMargin` and the `topMargin` on the view to move.

When I try it on a `Xperia Arc S`, I can set the `topMargin` and move the view vertically without any problem. But once I try to move it horizontaly (Setting the `leftMargin`), it doesn't work. I can't even set the `leftMargin` programatically.

I got a very simple code, but I can't find out what is going wrong on the `Xperia` and why it does work on the other devices I got.

```
params.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY() - view.getHeight();
params.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX() - (view.getWidth() / 2);

// Set bounds
if (params.topMargin < 0) params.topMargin = 0;
if (params.topMargin + viewHeight * 3/2 > display.heightPixels) params.topMargin = display.heightPixels - viewHeight * 3/2;
if (params.leftMargin < 0) params.leftMargin = 0;
if (params.leftMargin + viewWidth > display.widthPixels) params.leftMargin = display.widthPixels - viewWidth;

view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

If I display the values of `leftMargin`, `display.widthPixels` and `viewWidth`, I got something which look good. (Eg. `leftMargin` = anything between -100 to 600 or so. `widthPixels` = 480 and `viewWidth` = 316 at the moment).

Is there something wrong with the `Xperia` or is there any error in my code ?

Thanks for your precious help.

**EDIT: Solution was (Regarding Ved Prakash post)**

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams paramsOld = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(paramsOld.width, paramsOld.height, Gravity.TOP);

params.topMargin = (int) event.getRawY() - view.getHeight();
params.leftMargin = (int) event.getRawX() - (view.getWidth() / 2);

// Set bounds
if (params.topMargin < 0) params.topMargin = 0;
if (params.topMargin + viewHeight * 3/2 > display.heightPixels) params.topMargin = display.heightPixels - viewHeight * 3/2;
if (params.leftMargin < 0) params.leftMargin = 0;
if (params.leftMargin + viewWidth > display.widthPixels) params.leftMargin = display.widthPixels - viewWidth;

view.setLayoutParams(params);

view.invalidate();
```

Comment: Is padding an option over margin? If yes, you may try it.

Comment: What do you mean ? The `view` is a simple `LinearLayout` with `wrap_content` for both `height` and `width`. There is no padding and I can see the element is only taking 25% of the screen width. Which is very disapointing, is that it works perfectly on my HTC but not on my Xperia.

Comment: Are you explicitly invalidating the view by calling invalidate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sony Xperia Arc S* - `Android 2.3`

*HTC One* - `Android 4.1`

There is a problem in setting the layout with older versions of android.

Check the post: [android-setting-left-right-margin-doesnt-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522126/android-setting-left-right-margin-doesnt-work).

Comment: My Arc S is running android 4.0.4 (official rom).

Comment: Thank you very much the link you post was the solution

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.4 has some problem with layout Margin. So better try:

```
view.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```