# Why ImageView in XML and Java measurement different?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-imageview

I have the following XML for an ImageView:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/crossy"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

When I run the following code:

```
iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
Log.i("IV WxH", ""+iv.getWidth() + " " + iv.getHeight());
```

`LogCat` shows the following:

`02-05 23:56:04.116: I/IV WxH(10211): 24 24`

How do I ensure the height and width stays the same in code as it is in XML?

Comment: `getWidth` and `getHeight` return `px` but you use `dp` , then if you test on multi device you get Different number

Comment: How can I modify so I don't experience the issue...?

Comment: why you want modify that? what you want exactly?

Comment: I am allowing user to drag within a layout and since the java code uses px instead of DP, the thumb which moves with the user gesture goes off the layout. Which I am guessing because the measurements are different from XML and Java...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dp` in your XML file indicates a measurement unit of "density independent pixels", while the value logged from your Java code is telling you the measurement in actual pixels.

px = dp * (dpi / 160)

So in this case, you have a 320 dpi screen, so every 1 density independent pixels is 2 physical pixels.

If you want the measurement in physical pixels, replace `dp` with `px` in your XML file.  However, realize that on a device with lower dpi, your Imageview will take up a larger portion of the screen.

Comment: This is right.  If you want actual pixels, use px.  But that probably won't give you the result you want across devices.

Comment: How do I go around the issue? It's needed for an app I am creating.

Comment: I want it to be same across devices

Comment: I updated the answer... but I can't actually imagine that doing this is what you actually need to do... if you want it take up the same percentage of the screen on all devices, you need to use dp.

Comment: Thank you. I am creating a color picker which the user can drag inside a layout and now I see why the crosshair keeps going out of the layout, it's because of DP and PX difference

Answer (score 3):

`View.getWidth()` and `View.getHeight()` return in `px` so convert to `dp`

```
     dp = px / (dpi / 160);

    int width=View.getWidth();

    int widthdp=width/160;
```

**dpi** varies for different screens so check dpi for the [MultipleScreen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

compare this dp with your xml value.

Comment: How would I do it in my case?