# Are Android Tween Animations Always Twitchy / Jerky?

Tags: android, android-animation

When I do a simple tween animation in a new project, regardless if I'm moving an image or a say a button,
the animation is jerky / twitchy. On physical devices such as the S3 & RAZR.

Am I doing something wrong? Why would simple tween animations for moving a view in an IDE boilerplate app be twitchy / jerky on modern (4.x) devices?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    // called from a button's on click
    public void doImageAnimation(View view) {
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mciamge);
            iv.setY(200f);

            ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(iv, "x",1000);
            oa.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            oa.setRepeatCount(5);
            oa.setDuration(3000l);
            oa.start();
    }

    // called from a button's on click
    public void doButtonAnimation(View view) {                
            Button iv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mcbutton);
            iv.setX(0f);

            ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(iv, "x",1000);
            oa.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            oa.setRepeatCount(5);
            oa.setDuration(3000l);
            oa.start();
    }        

}
```

Comment: Have you tried speeding up the duration?  If you have an animation that's too slow, it can seem kinda choppy because it'll move a single pixel every x milliseconds.  Other factors are the complexity of the bitmaps on the views and how many views are in the hierarchy.

Comment: I haven't tried speeding up the duration. The animation needs to move slow, as I need to copy what was done on the iOS version of this app :(

Comment: Instead of speeding up the animation, try increasing the range of pixels to move.  Currently you're moving 1000 pixels over 3 seconds which amounts to about 63 pixels every 250 ms.  On a high res device, this is very small distance while on a high res device, it's quite far which will also look "choppy".  Convert the pixels to DP pixels based on your device.

Comment: DeeV, what you said sounds promising. But I don't know how to do what you're saying. How do I do that with ObjectAnimator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp  Get the pixels from that and replace the "1000" with the result.  If it does work, I'll convert all this to an answer.

Comment: Hmmmm...so I'm looking at top for the amount of processor power this is taking. 11-15% CPU on Droid Razr, 8-11% CPU on Galaxy S3.

The DP -> pixels...I still end up with a pixel value I need to give as an argument to the ObjectAnimator. 

However you did give me a idea! The _less_ distance moved, the less choppy movement and less CPU used. So I had values moving too far & now they're not as choppy when they don't move as far.

So like you said, quite far! Thank you!