# How to get the size in dip of the screen

Tags: android, screen

I searched this question, and almost all of the answers are like this:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
int width = dm.widthPixels;
```

But the official document says `widthPixels` is `The absolute width of the display in pixels.` I run the code above on my Nexus 5, and the width equals 1080. Obviously it is an Pixel value. Is there anything I missed? How can I get a dip value of the screen?

Comment: I don't think you can, DIP is density independent and not measured in actual realworld units.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it's correct, therfore only a comment.. dip == dp as said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android). Further, you can get px from dp and the other way round as given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12147550/1798304). Therefore, I assume you can just combine what you've got with the answer of the 2nd link.

Comment: @MalaKa I did as you said, it works for me to use `float width_dp = dm.widthPixels / dm.density;` Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should convert the result to dips, like:

```
private int pixelsToDips(int pixels)
{
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (pixels / scale + 0.5f);
}
```

Comment: What's the meaning of `0.5f`? I put a Button with `pixels / scale` width size, it really has a thin vacancy on the edge.When I use `pixels / scale + 0.5f` as you said, it exactly fit my screen.But why need to add `0.5f`?Does it applies all screen sizes?

Comment: I test `match_parent`, the thin vacancy disappear again in Android Studio.So I guess it is not necessary to add `0.5f`

Comment: If you cast `4.6f` to an int, the int will have 4 as a value. But if you add `0.5f` before casting the int will have the value 5. This means `int x = (int) (4.6f + 0.5f);` is the same as `int x = Math.round(4.6f)`.