# Setting ImageView size programmatically depending on resolution

Tags: android, imageview, screen-resolution, layoutparams

I have an `ImageView` which I want to set the size of **programmatically**. So I don't have the option of putting different-sized images in their respective `drawable` folders.

Basically, instead of doing what I've done below, I want to set the `LayoutParams` according to the screen resolution. If the device is `ldpi` or `mdpi`, then `100,100`... if it was `hdpi`, then `150,150` etc. How can I achieve this?

```
ImageVIew imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100));
layout.add(imageView);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
ImageVIew imageView = new ImageView(this);
int size = getImageSize();
imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(size , size ));
layout.add(imageView);
```

and your `getImageSize` function will be

```
private int getImageSize(){
         int density= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
         int size =100; 
         switch(density)
         {
         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
             size = 100;
             break;
         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
             size = 100;
             break;
         case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
             size = 150;
             break;
         }

         return size;
       }
```

where `getImageSize` return different size as per different density.

Answer (score 1):

First get `screen width`, and multiply it with what you want. I multiplied with `0,2`

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                   getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                   int screen_width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
                   int icon_width = screen_width * 2 / 10;
```

Then

```
ImageVIew imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(icon_width, icon_width));
layout.add(imageView);
```

Answer (score 1):

once i have used this:

```
 int density= getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;

switch(density)
{
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
Toast.makeText(context, "LDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
 Toast.makeText(context, "MDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
Toast.makeText(context, "HDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
 Toast.makeText(context, "XHDPI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

***Use `DisplayMetrics` to get the device dpi value in pixels -***

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

// Display device dpi value of Y in pixels
int screenDPIy = (int)dm.ydpi;

if (screenDPIy <= 180) 
{           
    ImageVIew imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(100, 100));
    layout.add(imageView);
}
else
{
    ImageVIew imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(150, 150));
    layout.add(imageView);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find out which densitity the device has, you can use:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
switch(metrics.densityDpi){
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                 break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use density independent pixels. Works programmatically using the strategy here: [Converting pixels to dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp)

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
int width = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
int height= (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, height));
layout.add(imageView);
```