# Android: Is line length in PX or DIP?

Tags: android, android-view

I have a custom view.

When I draw a line from (x,y) to (x+10,y), is the distance in DIP or PX?

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) says,

> At runtime, the system transparently handles any scaling of the dp
>   units, as necessary, based on the actual density of the screen in use.

Thus, all units are in **dp**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one of the `Canvas.drawLine` methods it is in PX

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's in pixels.  If you want to know how to convert from DP to pixels as in if you want your custom view to work with DPs just like all other Views.

[Converting pixels to dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp)