# Setting textSize in custom view results in huge text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I'm calling the following in the constructor of my custom view:

```
private void style(Resources.Theme theme, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.StackedTextView,
            0, 0);

    try {
        DebugTool.assertTrue(holdr != null, "View holder has not been properly intialized.");
        String line1 = a.getString(R.styleable.StackedTextView_line1);
        setLine1(line1);
        String line2 = a.getString(R.styleable.StackedTextView_line2);
        setLine2(line2);

        line1Size = a.getDimension(R.styleable.StackedTextView_line1_textSize, 20);
        line2Size = a.getDimension(R.styleable.StackedTextView_line2_textSize, 20);
        if (line1Size > 0) {
            holdr.textLine1.setTextSize(line1Size);
        }
        if (line2Size > 0) {
            holdr.textLine2.setTextSize(line2Size);
        }

    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

It's supposed to set text and text size for 2 textfields.

I have the following in my attr.xml in addition to the string formats for the text content (which works fine).

```
    <attr name="line1_textSize" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="line2_textSize" format="dimension" />
```

When I use this view and set the text size using a dimension via xml,

```
        <com.me.app.view.component.StackedTextView
            android:id="@+id/overview_total_reviews"
            app:line1="40"
            app:line2="Rating"
            style="@style/OverviewStackedText"
            app:line1_textSize="10sp"
            app:line2_textSize="12sp"
            />
```

the text ends up being significantly larger than expected. I'm only setting 10 and 12sp respectively, and the text sizes are closer to like 30sp.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Do I need to do something with DisplayMetrics to make sure things are scaled properly?

**Edit: Adding some clarification**

The dimension IS getting picked up. The text does change when I set the different text sizes using my custom attribute (in xml). I've also tried using `getDimensionPixelSize`.

It's as if the calculation/dimension retrieval is wrong. 1sp (or dp) change results in a significant change.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
line1Size = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.StackedTextView_line1_textSize, 0);
line2Size = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.StackedTextView_line2_textSize, 0);

if (line1Size > 0) {
    holdr.textLine1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, line1Size);
}
if (line2Size > 0) {
    holdr.textLine2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, line2Size);
}
```

Comment: To add some clarification to this correct solution, I needed to first retrieve the dimension in pixels and then set the text size by passing the unit/type of the dimension I was passing in the 2nd arg. Yeesh.

Comment: My fault. The default `setTextSize()` uses `COMPLEX_UNIT_SP` and result in this bug.

Answer (score 2):

@loeschg I had the same problem, but I finally managed to solve using @plackemacher 's reply more that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp)

Method .getDimensionPixelSizealways() returns the value in pixel, so you have to use convertPixelsToDp method to get the dp value.

Here is the code that can help you:

```
 /**
 * This method converts device specific pixels to density independent pixels.
 * 
 * @param px A value in px (pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into db
 * @param context Context to get resources and device specific display metrics
 * @return A float value to represent dp equivalent to px value
 */
public static float convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    return px / ((float) context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
}

line1Size = convertPixelsToDp(a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.StackedTextView_line1_textSize, 0), some_context);
line2Size = convertPixelsToDp(a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.StackedTextView_line2_textSize, 0), some_context);

if (line1Size > 0) {
    holdr.textLine1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, line1Size);
}
if (line2Size > 0) {
    holdr.textLine2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, line2Size);
}
```