# Place view in activity programmatically

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint

I'm trying to draw a circumference that would represent the battery life in a activity.

My parent layout is a relative layout.

This is the inner class that draws the view:

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG |
                Paint.DITHER_FLAG |
                Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);

        int size = 200;
        int radius = 190;
        int delta = size - radius;
        int arcSize = (size - (delta / 2)) * 2;
        int percent = 42;

        //Thin circle
        canvas.drawCircle(size, size, radius, mPaint);

        //Arc
        mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.eCarBlue));
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(15);
        RectF box = new RectF(delta,delta,arcSize,arcSize);
        float sweep = 360 * percent * 0.01f;
        canvas.drawArc(box, 0, sweep, false, mPaint);
    }

}
```

And in onCreate() I start the view this way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ...

    ViewGroup myLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
    drawing = new DrawView(this);
    myLayout.addView(drawing);
}
```

But I need to locate this view in the layout, especifically in the center of it. To achieve this, I have modified onCreate()'s code this way:

```
ViewGroup myLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
drawing = new DrawView(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
drawing.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
myLayout.addView(drawing);
```

But it isn't having effect on the view. What would be then the correct way to define the params for the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding `DrawView` with `LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`, which means the system needs to ask the view its width and height. You should implement `onMeasure()` for that. But I've never done that so don't know the details.

Another way is to just use `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` and draw your stuff in `onDraw()` centered yourself. In this case you will need to know the width and height of the canvas in order to calculate the coordinates of your draw calls. Calling `getWidth()` in `onDraw()` does not give you the expected results. You need to override `onSizeChanged()` and record the new width and height, like this:

```
private int canvasWidth;
private int canvasHeight;

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasWidth = w;
    canvasHeight = h;
}
```

Then in `onDraw()` you can use `canvasWidth` and `canvasHeight` because the `onSizeChanged()` has already happened.

Comment: Well, I have done something like this few minutes before. I have realized that I can center the view in onDraw and for that I have used getWidth() and getHeight() and has centered the view. Now I have changed that with you method using onSizeChanged, maybe is better approach but the result is the same. Anyway, your answer to the question is right.

Comment: Just one more thing... In an old device, the view has the desired size, but in a Galaxy S5 is smaller than in the old device. i think this has something to do with the `radius` value. How can I set the radius value to be the same in all screen densities?

Comment: The radius is in pixels which would look different on screens with different pixel densities. Android has the concept of a device independent pixel (dip) which is equivalent to a physical pixel on a 160 pixels per inch screen. So 16 dips would be 0.1 inch on any screen. I guess that is what you need. So translate from dips to pixels. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp) SO question for details how.