# Add bigger margin to EditText in Android AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, margin, padding, android-alertdialog

I have an EditText inside an AlertDialog. It looks like this.

[image]

See where it says tddjdjck and how it is indented quite a lot. That is what I want (I used `setPadding` with left and right set to 50), but I also want the blue line under it to be indented too. How do I do that?

The code I am using is below:

```
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(thisActivity);
            final EditText input = new EditText(thisActivity);
            input.setSingleLine();
            input.setPadding(50, 0, 50, 0);

            alert.setTitle("by...");
            alert.setMessage("enter the name of the person who did:");
            alert.setView(input);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String value = input.getText().toString().trim();

                }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
```

Thank you

Comment: instead of padding use layout_margin from left and right

Comment: Do it like this. settext("your text \n\n"). Simple and does the job

Comment: What function can I use to set the layout_margin?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(thisActivity);
final EditText input = new EditText(thisActivity);
input.setSingleLine();
FrameLayout container = new FrameLayout(thisActivity);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new  FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.leftMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.dialog_margin);
input.setLayoutParams(params);
container.addView(input);
alert.setTitle("by...");
alert.setMessage("test message");
alert.setView(container);
```

Make sure you add another line to your dimens.xml resource file, such as

```
<dimen name="dialog_margin">20dp</dimen>
```

Comment: Unfortunately we have wrap the EditText in a FrameLayout since the builder obliterates the layoutparams of whatever is added via setView. Not such an expensive deal here, but view hierarchies should always be as flat as possible.

Comment: Is there a better way than hardcoding the margin? Is there a like a style constant in R. so that the title margin and this margin always stay the same?

Comment: This did not work for me (with a `TextView` instead of a `EditText` ). The answer by Bhargav Thanki did work however.

Comment: Crashes with "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

Answer (score 26):

You can pass spacing parameter in `setView` method

```
alert.setView(view ,left_space , top_space , right_space , bottom_space);
```

So,in your case you can try this

```
alert.setView(input , 50 ,0, 50 , 0);
```

Comment: This is deprecated for newer APIs

Comment: @JensBrulmans but it still works without putting a dozen extra lines of code.

Comment: My builder only accepts one parameter for `setView()`

Comment: @jbrulmans Only the method in the Builder is deprecated. The method in the `AlertDialog` does not seem to be deprecated and achieves the same effect (called after `.create()` on the builder).

Answer (score 15):

Here is Kotlin extension function for the Builder to set EditText view.

```
val Float.toPx: Int
get() = (this * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).toInt()

fun AlertDialog.Builder.setEditText(editText: EditText): AlertDialog.Builder {
    val container = FrameLayout(context)
    container.addView(editText)
    val containerParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
    val marginHorizontal = 48F
    val marginTop = 16F
    containerParams.topMargin = (marginTop / 2).toPx
    containerParams.leftMargin = marginHorizontal.toInt()
    containerParams.rightMargin = marginHorizontal.toInt()
    container.layoutParams = containerParams

    val superContainer = FrameLayout(context)
    superContainer.addView(container)

    setView(superContainer)

    return this
}
```

**Usage example**

```
val editText = EditText(this)
AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Group Name")
        .setEditText(editText)
        .setPositiveButton("OK", { _: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
            // Do your work with text here
            val text = editText.text.toString()
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
        .show()
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I make a general single input AlertDialog function. The code is self-explanatory.

[image]

**Utils.java**

```
public class Utils {

    /**
     * Convert dp to px value.
     * -
     * Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6327095/2263329
     */
    public static int dpToPx(float dp, Resources resources) {
        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
        return (int) px;
    }

    /**
     * Show an AlertDialog with a single input box.
     *
     * @param context         Application context
     * @param title           Dialog title
     * @param message         Dialog input message/hint
     * @param inputType       InputType of EditText
     * @param positiveBtnText Dialog positive button text
     * @param negativeBtnText Dialog negative button text
     * @param listener        Dialog buttons click listener
     */
    public static void showSingleInputDialog(
            @NonNull Context context,
            @NonNull String title,
            @NonNull String message,
            int inputType,
            @NonNull String positiveBtnText,
            @NonNull String negativeBtnText,
            @NonNull final SingleInputDialogListener listener
    ) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alert.setTitle(title);

        TextInputLayout textInputLayout = new TextInputLayout(context);

        final EditText input = new EditText(context);
        input.setSingleLine(true);
        input.setInputType(inputType);
        input.setHint(message);

        FrameLayout container = new FrameLayout(context);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        int left_margin = Utils.dpToPx(20, context.getResources());
        int top_margin = Utils.dpToPx(10, context.getResources());
        int right_margin = Utils.dpToPx(20, context.getResources());
        int bottom_margin = Utils.dpToPx(4, context.getResources());
        params.setMargins(left_margin, top_margin, right_margin, bottom_margin);

        textInputLayout.setLayoutParams(params);

        textInputLayout.addView(input);
        container.addView(textInputLayout);

        alert.setView(container);

        alert.setPositiveButton(positiveBtnText, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                listener.positiveCallback(input.getText().toString());

            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton(negativeBtnText,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        listener.negativeCallback();

                    }
                });

        alert.show();
    }

}
```

**SingleInputDialogListener.java**

```
public interface SingleInputDialogListener {

    void positiveCallback(String inputText);

    void negativeCallback();

}
```

**Use example:**

```
Utils.showSingleInputDialog(mContext,
        "Password recovery",
        "Your e-mail address",
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
        "Recover",
        "Cancel",
        new SingleInputDialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void positiveCallback(String inputText) {

                Toast.makeText(mContext, inputText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void negativeCallback() {

                // ...

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        float paddingDp = 10f;
        int paddingPx = 5;


            paddingPx = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, 
                         paddingDp, activity.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
           //alert dialog
           adDialog.SetView(input, paddingPx, 5, paddingPx, 5);
```

try this below extension
i did this For xamarin android ,i hope this will work for Java as well with little modifications

```
 public static AlertDialog ShowInputDialogue(this Activity activity, string title, string message, string txtValue, string dismissButtonText, string submitButtonText, Action<string> OnSubmit,bool TextInputType =false,bool isEdittable =true)
    {
        AlertDialog adDialog = null;
        try
        {
            adDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).Create();
            // Create TextView
            EditText input = new EditText(activity);
            input.ImeOptions = Android.Views.InputMethods.ImeAction.Done;
            input.Enabled = isEdittable;
            float paddingDp = 10f;
            int paddingPx = 5;
            if (!TextInputType)
            {
                input.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.edit_text_shape);
                input.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber | Android.Text.InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal;
                input.Text = txtValue;
                //input.SetMaxLines(5);
                //input.SetLines(5);
            }
            else
            {
                input.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Color.edit_text_shape);

                // Convert to pixels
                paddingPx = (int)TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Dip, paddingDp, activity.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
                input.SetPadding(paddingPx, paddingPx, paddingPx, paddingPx);

                input.Text = txtValue;
                input.SetMaxLines(5);
                input.SetLines(5);
            }
            //input.FocusChange += (object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs e) =>
            //{
            //    // request a soft keyboard.
            //    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            //    if (e.HasFocus)
            //        imm.ToggleSoftInput(ShowFlags.Forced, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
            //};


            input.EditorAction += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.ActionId == ImeAction.Done)
                {
                    adDialog.Hide();
                    adDialog.Cancel();

                    if (OnSubmit != null)
                        OnSubmit(input.Text);


                }

            };


            //adDialog.Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable | WindowManagerFlags.AltFocusableIm);
            adDialog.SetTitle(title);
            adDialog.SetMessage(message);
            adDialog.SetView(input, paddingPx, 5, paddingPx, 5);
            adDialog.SetButton(dismissButtonText, new EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>(
                (s, args) =>
                {
                    adDialog.Hide();
                    adDialog.Cancel();

                    View view = adDialog.CurrentFocus;
                    if (view != null)
                    {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                        imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(view.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
                    }
                }));
            adDialog.SetButton2(submitButtonText, new EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>(
                (s, args) =>
                {
                    if (OnSubmit != null)
                        OnSubmit(input.Text);

                    View view = adDialog.CurrentFocus;
                    if (view != null)
                    {
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
                        imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(view.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
                    }
                }));
            adDialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.DialogAnimation_2;

            adDialog.Show();
            //input.RequestFocus();
            SetDialogueTheme(activity, adDialog);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return adDialog;
    }
```

Usage in activity:

```
   this.ShowInputDialogue("Title", "", "editetext notes", "Cancel", "Save", async (val) =>
                        {
                        try
                        {
                         //handle for save

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                          
                        }
                    }, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

### In Kotlin you can do it like this:

the margin values need to be set in px and if you want to use dp-values then dont forget to convert it to px.

```
editText.updateLayoutParams<FrameLayout.LayoutParams> {
    this.leftMargin = 50
    this.rightMargin = 50
}
```

**Important!** you need to update the layout params after setting the view in the AlertDialog

**You can see it in this example:**

```
val editText = EditText(this)
editText.setText("tddjdjck")

AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("by...")
    .setMessage("enter the name of the person who did:")
    .setView(editText)
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel"){ dialog, _ ->
        dialog.cancel()
    }.setPositiveButton("Ok"){ dialog, _ ->
        //your execution
    }.show()

editText.updateLayoutParams<FrameLayout.LayoutParams> {
    this.leftMargin = 50
    this.rightMargin = 50
}
```