# Position TextViews on the screen

Tags: android, layout, view

I have a board for my game and I want to place numbers over each one of the black windows
[image: Before] [image: After]

```
      What my board looks like ----------------------> What I want to achieve
```

I know which are the (x,y) coordinates to which the numbers will have to be placed, based on the Full HD image I'm using as a background; since the background is the same for all resolutions, I apply a scaling based on the device screen size. Nevertheless the numbers are all placed in the wrong position, with different distances between each other and not vertically aligned.
[image: Current result]

The following is the relevant code:

```
public class GraphicsActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private GraphicsSurfaceView view;
private static int[] player1positionX = {1556, 1325, 1101, 810, 587, 356};
private static int[] player1positionY = {886, 709, 886, 886, 709, 886};
private static int[] player2positionX = {356, 587, 810, 1101, 1325, 1556};
private static int[] player2positionY = {182, 361, 182, 182, 361, 182};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getRealSize(size);
    float scaleX = size.x / 960f;
    float scaleY = size.y / 540f;
    view = new GraphicsSurfaceView(this, scaleX, scaleY);
    LinearLayout bowlsPlayer1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout bowlsPlayer2 = new LinearLayout(this);
    gameBoard.addView(view);
    gameBoard.addView(bowlsPlayer1);
    gameBoard.addView(bowlsPlayer2);
    setContentView(gameBoard);

    /** Some code **/

    for (int i = 0; i < Game.BOWL_NUMBER; i++) {
        TextView bowl1 = new TextView(GraphicsActivity.this);
        bowl1.setText(String.valueOf(Game.INITIAL_SEED));
        bowl1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        bowl1.setTextSize(40);
        bowl1.setX(player1positionX[i] / scaleX);
        bowl1.setY(player1positionY[i] / scaleY);
        bowlsPlayer1.addView(bowl1);
        TextView bowl2 = new TextView(GraphicsActivity.this);
        bowl2.setText(String.valueOf(Game.INITIAL_SEED));
        bowl2.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        bowl2.setTextSize(40);
        bowl2.setX(player2positionX[i] / scaleX);
        bowl2.setY(player2positionY[i] / scaleY);
        bowlsPlayer2.addView(bowl2);
    }
}
```

How can I correctly place the numbers on the screen?

**EDIT 1:**
After `Der Golem` suggestion I switched from [pixel to dp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9563438/1006156); this was useful to work better with the coordinates I had. I also switched from a `LinealLayout` to a `RelativeLayout` in which to insert the numbers and finally they are put all at the same distance.
[image: Actual result]

How can I center the numbers placing the center of the TextView on the coordinates and not the upper left corner?

Comment: Where are you getting 960 and 540 from? If those are your width and height, then you have quite a view player position values that lie outside of that range.

Comment: Because of some animations on the background, each frame is resized to 960x540

Comment: You are reasoning in **px** (resolution based). But Android bases its scaling on **dp** (density based). So, you first have to get the scale factor for the current screen density and then calculate the coordinates in **px**. Also mind that you should provide your graphics in different densities... Some graphics may be optimized by using 9 patches and/or Android drawables.