# Passing from one unit to another in android?

Tags: android, pixel

Well, i been trying to figure out, is there a simple way to pass from  dp or milimetres or even inches to px. (like: 6dp would be 20px)
It seems everything is usually done in px but i want to use these in orther to keep the proportions in different screens and have a rough sense of how big is going to be (guessing with pixels feels really...bothering)
Thanks in advance and sorry if the question is too vague.

Comment: This might be the answer you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp

Comment: Im not sure it is. what kind of class is TypedValue?

Comment: @qerahile it's a class that allows you to convert from one unit to another http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to convert  milimetres or even inches to px programmatically. If you want to support different screens, you can follow the document [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html).
To convert dp to px, you can also use the following method:

```
/**
 * Convert dp to px.
 * @param context 
 * @param dp the input dp.
 * @return the output px.
 */
public static int dpToPx(Context context, int dp) {
    float density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return (int) (dp * density + 0.5);
}
```

**Update:**

Here is how to get a device's width and height pixels:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int widthPixels = metrics.widthPixels;
int heightPixels = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for! One more thing, so you cant know the width and height of a device(in metrics or pixels)?

Comment: Yes, you can know the width and height of a device in pixels, see my update. But, in order to support many screens, you must consider use dp instead of px.