# How to resize image's dpi from 96dpi to 72dpi

Tags: java, android, image, performance

I resize my cellphone's images to 731*974,but it still has 920KB. So I want to change the image resolution from 96dpi to 72dpi(because I found the pictures in iPhone is 72dpi,and it looks good). Anyone can give a clue to do this job? First thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at [this](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/).
In Android resolutions differ a lot, one image might not be suitable for all phone resolutions.

Comment: 72dpi is enough for me to show images on my application. My app should upload and download many images,so I should minimum the image and keep the image looks well. From now I saw 72dpi is good.

Comment: Okay, in that case you can use [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605527/converting-pixels-to-dp) to see how to get the values in px for 72dpi on each phone, and then rescale your `Bitmap` using  `Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap()`