# Snackbar behind navigation bar

Tags: android, navigationbar, snackbar

In landscape mode, I am using

```
    window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);
```

to show and hide navigation bar.

When I create Snackbar while navigation is showing

```
Snackbar bar  = Snackbar.make(snackbarContainer, "exiting", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    bar.setAction("Testing", new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //no-op
        }
    });
    bar.show();
```

The Snackbar's action text is being covered by the navigation bar.
Is there a way to adjust snackbar's width automatically based on whether the navigation bar is showing or not?

Answer (score 4):

Possibly you are searching for this:

```
private void displaySnackBarWithBottomMargin(Snackbar snackbar, int sideMargin, int marginBottom) {
    final View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) snackBarView.getLayoutParams();

    params.setMargins(params.leftMargin + sideMargin, params.topMargin, params.rightMargin + sideMargin, params.bottomMargin + marginBottom);

    snackBarView.setLayoutParams(params);
    snackbar.show();
}
```

Actually found it at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844669/371749

If you add the margin bottom from the navigation bar height **(48dp)** it perfectly appears above the navigation bar.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a `CoordinatorLayout` (for instance when using a `ConstraintLayout`, tie it to the bottom of the parent).

Next, give the id of the `CoordinatorLayout` to the `Snackbar.make(...)` function (or any child in the `CoordinatorLayout`).

A snackbar will iterate the views from the current one up until it finds a `CoordinatorLayout` and attach itself to it.