# SnackBar goes behind NavigationBar after using FLAG_NO_LIMIT

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I am trying to focus designing like this:

[image]

for this, I have added inside onCreate

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Now Layout got expanded but it somehow hides my snackbar behind the nav bar which is not the desired result as it should be above.Here's my screenshot:

[image]

I might have approached wrong way and it would be very helpful if you correct me.

Comment: View rootView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView, message, 2000);


    @Droidwala,    View sView = snackbar.getView();
        TextView textView = (TextView) sView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844669/4858147): add margins for your snackbar, **48dp** should be enough.

```
public static void displaySnackBarWithBottomMargin(Snackbar snackbar, int sideMargin, int marginBottom) {
    final View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
    final CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) snackBarView.getLayoutParams();

    params.setMargins(params.leftMargin + sideMargin,
                params.topMargin,
                params.rightMargin + sideMargin,
                params.bottomMargin + marginBottom);

    snackBarView.setLayoutParams(params);
    snackbar.show();
}
```

Comment: Careful with FrameLayout cast Exception

Comment: I ran into that hehe

Answer (score 0):

Do not use "rootView" instance for creating Snackbar, instead use getView() like below

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getView(), "Your Message", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
snackbar.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using this technique:

1- add a View to my layout

2- set Snackbar setAnchorView

> In your XML

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/snackBarAnchor"
        android:layout_width="0.1dp"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

> in your code

```
          snackbar.setAnchorView(R.id.snackBarAnchor)
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no need for guesswork with LayoutParams (which can leave your Snackbar in weird positions on different screens)

Instead just ensure the root of your layout is a `CoordinatorLayout`. Make sure the coordinator is also the View given to the snackbar (don't use `v.getRootView()` as this can be another view)

You may need to give an id to the coordinator and pass that as the view:

```
new Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.coordinator), ...).show()
```